# Sum time varchar

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, time, sql-server-2005

I have this table

[image]

And I just need sum column Duracao + Hora to obtain a new column named Return, like this: 
[image]

In correct scenario, result of column Return must be 18:06:07. How can I get it?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that Hora contains the varchar value 18:06:02 and Duracao contains the varchar value 00:00:05, you can convert them to `DATETIME`, then add them like so:

```
SELECT CONVERT(
               VARCHAR(8),
               DATEADD(
                       SECOND,
                       DATEDIFF(SECOND, 0, CAST(Duracao AS DATETIME)),
                       CAST(Hora AS DATETIME)
               ),
               108
        )
```

Comment: Msg 243, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Type Time is not a defined system type.

Comment: Are you using SQL server from the dinosaur age?

Comment: lol

Microsoft SQL Server 2005 - 9.00.1399.06 (X64) 
Oct 14 2005 00:35:21 
Copyright (c) 1988-2005 Microsoft Corporation
Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)

Welcome to my life =\

Comment: It'll work if both columns have same date -and- a very small date like 1900-01-01. If that is the case then you're good.